# Java Image Manipulation

Tags: java, image

I have a project where I must manipulate an image in multiple ways. I am stuck on pixelation.

For pixelation I must take a 10x10 set of pixels and return one cell that has averaged the RGB colors out individually. Currently all I get is a red image in my runner program. Thanks for the help.

```
public static Photograph pixelated(Photograph photo) {
        int red = 0;
        int green = 0;
        int blue = 0;
        int interval = 10;
        Photograph p = null;
        p = new Photograph(photo.getWidth(),photo.getHeight());
        for (int row=0; row<photo.getHeight(); row +=interval) {
            for (int col=0; col<photo.getWidth(); col +=interval) {

                for (int row2=row; row2<row+10; row2++) {
                    for (int col2=col; col2<col+10; col2++) {
                    red = red + photo.getPixel(col, row).getRed();
                    green = green + photo.getPixel(col, row).getGreen();
                    blue = blue + photo.getPixel(col, row).getBlue();   
                    }
                }
            red = red / interval;
            green = green / interval;
            blue = blue / interval;

            Pixel rgb = new Pixel(red,green,blue);
            for (int row3=0; row<interval; row++) {
                for (int col3=0; col<interval; col++) {
                    p.setPixel(col3, row3, rgb);
        }}}}
        return p;
        }
```

Comment: 1) `Pixel`, `Photograph`..?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) `}}}}` ???? Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Right off the bat you're adding up 100 pixel color values but dividing by only 10.  What does `Pixel(r,g,b)` do with values that are about 10x too big?

Comment: The }}}} really makes you think you prefer to program in python XD

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple of bugs in there.
You are not resetting the red green blue values between each block,
Good practice is to only have variable available for the scope they 
are required.

Interval was used intermittently.

Also as pointed out you were not getting the average correctly,
you also may want to consider rounding issues, this code truncates.

one thing to be aware of is that red green blue can sometimes be ints 
and sometimes floats you will get problems if you mix them up.

```
public static Photograph pixelated(Photograph photo) {
    int interval = 10;
    Photograph p = null;
    p = new Photograph(photo.getWidth(),photo.getHeight());
    for (int row=0; row<photo.getHeight(); row +=interval) {
        for (int col=0; col<photo.getWidth(); col +=interval) {
            // declare and reset variables here
            int red = 0;
            int green = 0;
            int blue = 0;

            for (int row2=row; row2<row+interval; row2++) {
                for (int col2=col; col2<col+interval; col2++) {
                    // i assume these functiosn return an int 0 <= x < 256 ?
                    red = red + photo.getPixel(col, row).getRed();
                    green = green + photo.getPixel(col, row).getGreen();
                    blue = blue + photo.getPixel(col, row).getBlue();   
                }
            }
            // you have a square not a line
            red = red / (interval * interval);
            green = green / (interval * interval);
            blue = blue / (interval * interval);

            // i assume this constructor takes ints 0 <= x < 256 ?
            Pixel rgb = new Pixel(red,green,blue);
            // interval needs to be used here
            for (int row3=row; row3< row+interval; row3++) {
                for (int col3=col; col3<col+interval; col3++) {
                    p.setPixel(col3, row3, rgb);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Explain what you changed and why, so the OP knows what went wrong and why